# VMDK File Growing After copying it using CP?

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage, freebsd, netapp, vmdk

Using FreeBSD and a mounted NetApp NFS Share.

I'm trying to copy a file

```
FROM: localdisk/something.vmdk (size 527776 kilobytes)
TO: nfsmount/copy-something.vmdk (size 533168 kilobytes)
```

But it seems like from the above size I've demonstrated that the file somehow grew after the action of copying. Even though I'm just trying to duplicate the file.

Any idea's how this could happen? I'm simply running

```
cp localdisk/something.vmdk nfsmount/copy-something.vmdk
```

Then running a du on each to check file size and they're mysteriously growing in size.

```
uname -rs
FreeBSD 8.1-RELEASE-p2
```

Comment: This can happen if the block sizes of the filesystems are different. Are the source and destinationss formatted differently?

Comment: If you want to confirm that you have an exact copy of the file, it's usually better to run `md5sum` on both and compare the hash. If it's the same you can be sure the file is exactly the same.

Comment: `du` reports disk space used not file size. For sparse files these are not the same. Does `ls -ls` show them the same size? (first column will be blocks used - may differ, latter size should be the same).

Comment: @Brian ls -ls still shows a difference. Source: 527776 Dst: 533168

Comment: @faker md5 reports a match: src: 224067840895a0499f2a0d8d33ecd185 dst: 224067840895a0499f2a0d8d33ecd185

Comment: @NathanC Do you know how I would check block sizes on NetApp? Can I do that over NFS? I dont have access to the Netapp admin. Here's what i got for bsd block dumpfs /d2/ | grep bsize
bsize   16384   shift   14      mask    0xffffc000
maxbsize 16384  maxbpg  2048    maxcontig 8     contigsumsize 8
sbsize  2048    cgsize  16384   csaddr  1680    cssize  497664

Comment: @NathanC Looks like netapp default block size is 4K on WAFL filesystem. So is there any way to make this play nicely? I'm trying to test dedupe but these differences are preventing it from happening.

Comment: Sure looks like a sparse file getting filled in with blocks or partial blocks filled with zeros on getting copied to another file system. That would be why the md5 for each is the same. Can you post the actual output from `ls -ls filename` for each?

Comment: @Brian i see now that one of the columns gives the same size but the initial size on the far left is different. What does each mean? ls -ls /images/something.vmdk
 527776 -rw-r--r--  1 user  domusers  543817728 Mar 24 16:20 /images/something.vmdk
ls -ls /netapp/images/copy-something.vmdk
 533168 -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  543817728 May  9 09:32 /netapp/images/copy-something.vmdk

Comment: The number on the far left is the number of blocks used on disk, same as what comes from `du`. The other number is the file size. Sparse files have holes in them where blocks that are all zeros aren't actually stored and don't take up any disk space. Google `sparse files` for why they exist and some of the drawbacks.

Comment: @Brian okay I understand now why one file may be larger than the other. What I'm still unsure about is why deduplication isn't working. It should still be able to dedupe the majority of the blocks of this file.

Comment: Dedupe is invisible to the client. On the filer - run: `sis start /vol/volname`. Monitor it with `sis status`. Then run `df -gs /vol/volname` which will show you used vs. saved on the filesystem. You cannot do this client side - the filer hides this information from you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, here's what I understand:

- You have a VM saved on a local disk
- You are trying to copy it to a Netapp NFS share with dedupe enabled to test dedupe

If this is true, the reason you're not seeing an immediate gain is probably that the deduplication on Netapp is post process. The Netapp does a bit-to-bit comparison of any candidate blocks as a background task before deduplicating (which replaces a duplicate block with a pointer to an original block). This process is managed centrally, so only your storage admin can tell you what the schedule is. It's a lot of reads, so people tend to not schedule it during, for example, backups.

Comment: You also won't see the dedupe saving on `ls` - you'll see the original file size. You may not even see it on `df`as that depends rather if the exported filesystem is a volume or (quotaed) qtree. And whether snapshots are enabled. (First pass dedupe saving probably moves into snapshots, and only actually saves space once snaps expire)

Comment: The asker specified that they're using du :)